# Question about 何も

Tags: meaning

In the following sentence, what does なにも mean?

> まあ なにも隠し事があるのは
> 彼らだけではないからな

Comment: Other duplicates: Also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77748/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69082/5010